# helping verbs in the past tense

Tags: past-perfect, past-participles, irregular-forms

[irregular-verbs-examples](https://www.thoughtco.com/irregular-verbs-in-all-tenses-1211151)

The link above describes some irregular verbs that require helping verbs (i.e., she had begun work before I arrived). I am trying to confirm whether one can choose to use a helping verb in the past perfect tense or if on has to one hundred percent of the time.

Another great resource for this kind of thing is:

[tense-cheat-sheet](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/grammar-explanations.html)

Like I've shown, I've done the research...would just like some clarification. My question is:

Yes or No: Is the reality of the English language that some verbs will have helping verbs in the past perfect tense and others will not?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking whether all auxiliary verbs have past participles?  In fact, some of them don't (notably the modals).

Comment: yes I'm asking that.

Comment: Has my answer answered your question then?  (And if not, would you like to clarify your question further? Thanks.)

Comment: Is the only downside of using this form so much that it can get quite redundant and you don't know how the action actually happened to get to the end result? I know that sounds like a leading question, but I'm trying to break it down to english-language learners so I need to make sure I can explain its place in the english language. (more clarification about the context of why I need to know about the helping verbs that was not appropriate in the initial question)

Comment: Redundant in what way?  There are some places where it doesn't work grammatically, other places where it is compulsory, and some where there is some variation in usage.  There is a tag past-vs-present-perfect for discussing the decision about when to use the present perfect versus when to use the simple past. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/past-vs-present-perfect

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ***all*** perfect constructions require a form of the auxiliary *HAVE*<sup>†</sup>, followed (with perhaps an intervening adverbial) by the past participle of its complement. In the past perfect the *HAVE* form will be the past form: ***had***.

<sup>†</sup><sub>In older English some verbs of motion might take the past form of the auxiliary *BE* instead of *HAVE*, but that construction is no longer employed except in literary contexts.</sub>

Comment: based on the website, some irregular verbs do not have that "had" that you're talking about....or is that an error with the particular source I used?

Comment: @Jackal21 Can you give an example from either page of a past perfect which does **not** employ *have*?

Answer (score 1):

The modal auxiliaries have no past participles and so don't have perfects of their own (although they can govern perfect infinitives).

So, "*can*", "*will*", "*shall"*, "*may"* have past forms "*could*", "*would*", "*should*", "*might*", but no past participles (nor present participles, nor infinitives).  However, even the past forms are more often used with non-past meaning than with past meaning, so some people prefer to think of them as separate verbs.  (For example, "could" often refers to a future potential event, as do "would" and "might".)

"*Must*" and "*ought*" also lack past participles (and present participles and infinitives), but these two verbs only have a single tense form, with no present/past distinction even notionally.

So, the past of "*I can*" is "*I could*", but there is no present perfect or past perfect.  If you needed one, you would have to use a workaround such as "*I have been able to*" (present perfect) and "*I had been able to*" (past perfect).  For "*must*", the workarounds are *"I have had to*" (present perfect) and "*I had had to*" (past perfect).

Although the modal verbs have no perfects of their own, they can govern perfect infinitives, e.g. "*I could have been*", "*I will have gone*", "*I would have known*", "*I might have done*".